# What are the options to host Orleans on Azure without using the Cloud Services?

Tags: azure, orleans

I want to host an Orleans project on Azure, but don't want to use the (classic) Cloud Services model (I want an ARM template project). The web app sample uses the old web / worker model - what is best option? There is a Service Fabric sample - is that the best route? The nearest equivalent to the web/worker model is VM Scale Sets - is that a well tested option?

Answer (score 2):

IMO, app service is closet to web role.

Worker role however, depending on the point of view

From system architecture point of view, I think Scale Set is the closet. You get an identical set of VMs running your application. However you lost all management features. How your cluster handle application configurations, work loads on each node, service interruptions from server failure or deployments are pretty much DIY. Also you need to provision the VM with dependencies for your application.

From operations point of view, I think Service Fabric is the closest. It handles problems above but then you are dealing with design/implementation changes and learning curve from the added fabric layer in the architecture. Could be small, could be big depending on the complexity of your project. Besides, service fabric is still relatively new and nothing is for sure. Best case you follow the sample change a few lines of code and it works like a charm. Worst case you may want to complete refactor orleans solution into service fabric solution.

App service would be the easiest among the three. If it doesn't meet your requirement, I personally would try Service Fabric. Same reason why people are moving to cloud and you would opt for ARM solution.